# Jquery Json parser showing invalid character error for jersey rest webservice response

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, jersey, jackson

I'm creating JSON by rest webservice MediaType property

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Issues getAllOpenPoints() {
```

I'm Using jackson jars for creating JSON response. So Not creating JSON manually but Still when trying to parse this response by jquery. It throws invalid characher error.

```
$.parseJSON(result);
```

Do I need to encode or escape the data in objects before returning from my rest webservice. but then whats the point of using Auto response conversion by Jackson.

Comment: Jackson should not produce invalid content, but perhaps javascript code is assuming different character set? While JSON is mandated, by specification, to be UTF encoded (usually UTF-8), some web standards indicate ISO-8859-1 as the default. So it is safest to ensure that response contains full type and character encoding definition; something like "application/json; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: Changed character encoding declaration in REST operation.
 `code@GET
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")

still jquery.js line number 550 which is below, is throwing an exception "Invalid character" at below line.
return window.JSON.parse( data );

Comment: Here's the XHR response body  from IE11 network tab. For debugging pirpose I'm adding only one object in returned collection of object graph. But its still failing

{"issue":[{"product":"MINI","dateReported":"06-12-2015","Summary":"dfgfg","status":"Open","responsiblePerson":"Manvendra\t","targetCompletionDate":"06-12-2015","completionDate":"06-12-2015","application":"Allocation","priority":1,"Comments":{"comment":[{"date":"06-12-2015","description":"sadfsdf"},{"date":"06-12-2015","description":"sadfsdf"}]}}]}

Comment: I wonder if it might for the tab character ('\t') in there. It is valid in JSON, as long as it is quoted. But perhaps jQuery does not like it for some reason.

Comment: Actually its related to that comments array variable. but unlike Jquery I cant see any issue with that. See my answer

Comment: What is the actual error message by JQuery?

Comment: It said "invalid character" on parsing. I really didn't have much time. so I changed my xml and java object structure. now its all fine. It was a single page internal application i developed for my client.
 I just proposed my client to show some data coming from a feed in Jquery tabs and accordion pane with the help of Json returned from rest web service.

Comment: got it. Was just curious to know what was going on, in case I or someone else encountered the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I know what is the problem in JSON parsing but still looking for the reason. Problem is due to the structure of object graph I have.

- First I designed the XML manually.
- Then generated schema from the XML
- Then used eclipse to create java Objects from that XSD.

Below is the XML I started with..

```
<issues>
  <issue>
    <product>XXXX</product>
    <dateReported>XXXX</dateReported>
    <Summary>XXXX</Summary>
    <status>XXXX</status>
    <responsiblePerson>XXXX </responsiblePerson>
    <targetCompletionDate>XXXX</targetCompletionDate>
    <completionDate>XXX</completionDate>
    <application>XXXX</application>
    <priority>XXXX</priority>
    <Comments>
        <comment>
            <date>XXXXX</date>
            <description>XXXXX</description>
        </comment>
        <comment>
            <date>XXXXX</date>
            <description>XXXXX</description>
        </comment>
    </Comments>
  </issue>
    ......
     ......
</issues>
```

Issue Class contains an object of type Comments and that comments object contains a list of object type comment. 
If I had started by creating JAVA object first instead of XML, then I would have kept a List of "Comment" in Issue class rather that one extra comments Object.

Now this is resulting in following JSON.

```
{
   "issue": [
      {
         "product": "XXXXX",
         "dateReported": "XXXXX",
         "Summary": "XXXXX",
         "statu‌​s": "XXXXX",
         "responsiblePerson": "XXXXX",
         "targetCompletionDate": "XXXXX",
         "‌​completionDate": "XXXXX",
         "application": "XXXXX",
         "priority": 1,
         "Comments":{
                ‌​"comment":[
                {
                   "date": "XXXXX",
                   "description": "XXXXX"
                },
                {
                   "date": "XXXXX",
                   "de‌​scription": "XXXXX"
                }
             ]
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

If I edit the JSON and try to parse following JSON in a sample JS file. it all works fine.

```
{
   "issue": [
      {
         "product": "XXXXX",
         "dateReported": "XXXXX",
         "Summary": "XXXXX",
         "statu??s": "XXXXX",
         "responsiblePerson": "XXXXX",
         "targetCompletionDate": "XXXXX",
         "??completionDate": "XXXXX",
         "application": "XXXXX",
         "priority": 1,
         "Comments": [
            {
               "date": "XXXXX",
               "description": "XXXXX"
            },
            {
               "date": "XXXXX",
               "de??scription": "XXXXX"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

But the first JSON is also a valid object representation.  Why an exception is thrown in parsing that ?